# how to use passport with angular node app?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, passport.js

I am working on a simple blog website based on `angular.js + node.js` and `mongodb` using express template. 
I hit with `$http` from angular controller by POST method to a api named `users.js` where login is authenticated using `passport.authenticate` method.
I require passport-local login strategies in `users.js`.
But it's not working.here is angular login service code and node users api code.
Can anybody tell me how can  use `passport.js` in angular and node?

**angular routing through a service**

```
app.service('Auth',function($location,$http,$localStorage){                  
  var userLogin ;
  return{
    setLogIN:function(email,password){
      $http({
         method: 'POST',
         url: '/users/login',  //users.js having node routing.
         data: {email:email, password:password},
      })
```

**node routing in user**

```
router.post('/login',passport.authenticate('local', { 
    // use passport-local for authentication
    successRedirect : '/profile', 
    failureRedirect : '/login', 
    failureFlash : true 
}));
```

**passport-local strategy**

```
app.use(passport.initialize());

app.use(passport.session());
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
    function (username, password, done) {

        User.findOne({username: username}, function (err, user) {

            if (err) {
                return done(err);
            }
            if (!user) {
                return done(null, false, {alert: 'Incorrect username.'});
            }
            if (user.password != password) {
                return done(null, false, {alert: 'Incorrect password.'});
            }
            return done(null, user);
        });
    }

));


passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
         done(err, user);
    });
});

function isAuthenticated(req,res,next){
    if(req.isAuthenticated())return next();
     res.redirect('/');
}
```

So I want to authenticate using passport, but use the client side templating/routing to keep the proper authentication.

Can someone please point me in the right direction? Or tell me if what I am doing is completely misguided?

**edit :** the error I AM getting with my code is it's not redirecting to profile page

> TypeError: POST http://localhost:3000/users/login   500 Internal
>   Server Error
>
> Not a valid User

Comment: Post the code of your authentication strategy also.

Answer (score 3):

i found solution to my question..
how to use passport with angular-nodejs routing.......

```
 //angular js routing
$scope.userlogin=function(){
    $http({
        method:"post",
        url:'/users/login',
        data:{username:$scope.username,password:$scope.password},
    }).success(function(response){
        $scope.userData = response;
        $localStorage.userData = $scope.userData; 
        console.log("success!!");
        $location.path("/profile")
    }).error(function(response){
        console.log("error!!");
        $location.path("/login")
    });
}
```

i use POST method and hit to node (users.js) controller and get      response from it. if user authentication is successful then it relocate to      profile view otherwise remain on login view.

```
//add these two lines to app.js
// var app = express();
app.use(passport.initialize());

app.use(passport.session());

//node routing 
// add  passport-stretegies to users.js
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(function(username, password, done) {
    user.findOne({username: username }, function(err, user) {
        if (err) { return done(err); }
        if (!user) {
            return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' });
        }
        if (user.password != password) {
            return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });
        }
        return done(null, user);
        // console.log(user)
    });
}));

 //passport serialize user for their session
 passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
     done(null, user.id);
 });
 //passport deserialize user 
 passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
     user.findById(id, function(err, user) {
         done(err, user);
     });
 });

 //router on same page
 router.post('/login',passport.authenticate('local'),function(req,res){

 res.send(req.user);
     //console.log(req.user);
 });
```

get a hit from angular side throught post method it use passport-local method for authentication if user is authenticated seccessfully then authenticated user is sent as response..

Answer (score 2):

By default, `LocalStrategy` expects dictionary parameters to be named `username` and `password`.

If you want to use `email` instead of `username`, then you should define them in your strategy:

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'email',
    passwordField: 'password'
  },
  function(username, password, done) {
    // ...
  }
));
```

For your case, it should be:

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'email',
    passwordField: 'password'
  },
function (username, password, done) {

    User.findOne({username: username}, function (err, user) {

        if (err) {
            return done(err);
        }
        if (!user) {
            return done(null, false, {alert: 'Incorrect username.'});
        }
        if (user.password != password) {
            return done(null, false, {alert: 'Incorrect password.'});
        }
        return done(null, user);
    });
}
));
```